# Play framework services integration testing in Jenkins CI

Tags: jenkins, playframework, sbt

I want to use Jenkins CI for integration testing with Play framework. My scenario is as following:

1. I have 2 projects, Project A and B.
2. Project A depends on Project B. The dependency is as such that to run tests on Project A, I need to start Project B first.
3. I already have unit tests in Project A but I need to test the integration of Project A and B.

I am using SBT plugin to execute the SBT and the Project A and Project B are working fine separately.

I could not figure out a proper way to do it. The issue I am facing is that I need to run Project B as a pre-build step but the Project B must be kept in running state but Project B is ended as soon as the build step executes `run` action of sbt and finishes the build which I don't want.

The command I execute to run Project B is `clean compile run` which executes as an action to SBT launcher.

I tried SBT `stage` and then run the jar but that is also causing the issue that the jar halts the control of the build and Project A doesn't get a chance to start.

I also checked [Spawning a process in Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build) but I couldn't make it work too. I am using Ubuntu and I tried using `nohup` instead of `daemonize` as described in the link by adding it as *Execute shell script* build step and it starts the Project B server process and kills it after some time. I also don't think that it might be the only way to do what I want to do.

May be I am using Jenkins wrong or may be I need to look in another direction so any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where I needed to free the console for running other stuff. I did something similar (i.e. creating a script with the sbt commands), then running the script with a nohup like so:

```
nohup ./myScript.sh &
```

and the Play! app runs just fine in the background.

Remember to use different ports in your case, since you're running two Play! apps.